# Select doesn't update

Tags: jquery, select, input

When I change select option, it doesn't update the value. The number of content inside box must change based of select option but it doesn't work. 
Thanks in advance.
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4rr66pnb/)

```js
$(function() {
  var all = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz\-=_!#%&'*{},.\/:?\(\)\[\]@\\$\^*+<>~";
  var myLength = $("#mySelect option:selected").val();

  function randomAll() {
    for (var i = 0; i < myLength; i++) {
      var word = all[Math.floor(Math.random() * all.length)];
      $('#content').append(word + i++);
    }
  }

  $('#all').click(function() {
    $('#content').html('');
    randomAll();
  });

});
```

```css
#content {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="all">All</button>
<div id="content"></div>
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="4" selected="selected">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get selected value inside the function

```
 function randomAll() {
        var myLength = $("#mySelect option:selected").val();
        for (var i = 0; i < myLength; i++) {
          var word = all[Math.floor(Math.random() * all.length)];
          $('#content').append(word + i++);
        }
      }
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/53sqstb0/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind to its `change` event

```
$('#mySelect').change(function(){
  $('#content').val($(this).val());
});
```

This will set it to the value of the option that is selected when it is changed.